# MPRemoteMediaPickerController timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MusicUIService

Tags: ios, itunes

MPRemoteMediaPickerController timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MusicUIService

I get this error on iOS7... only.

I saw another post regarding this error, but no one responded to it.

Cant find any solution on google either

Answer (score 2):

I just started receiving this when I first ran my app on iOS7.1.  I'm not even using MPRemoteMediaPickerController (directly).  I'm using MPMediaPickerController, but I'm purposefully reusing the object so the user goes back to the same place that they left the next time they choose a song.

In 7.1 I'm getting this warning and the picker displays a useless (can't cancel out) white view.

Solution was to toss the MPMediaPickerController after each use.  The error does not seem to happen if I have a fresh one each time.